# How does $u^Tv = p \cdot \|u\|$ follow from the projection onto line?

Tags: linear-algebra

Before anybody asks, this is not a homework question. I just saw the formula given in Andrew Ng's Coursera course in the SVM section.

For reference: the projection formula is 
$$
\mathrm{proj}_w(p) = w\frac{p \cdot w}{w \cdot w} 
$$
where $p$ and $w$ are vectors of the same dimension.

[Here's my working from the RHS, but I'm not really sure where to go.](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jq74a0&s=8#.VeXqxdNViko)

Comment: I think that you had a mistake in your formula, so I fixed it.  Let me know if I'm getting something wrong.

Comment: Also, your question is unclear.  $p$ seems to be a vector, which would mean that $p \cdot \|u\|$ is also a vector.  On the other hand, $u^Tv$ is a scalar.

Comment: read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

Comment: I didn't have a mistake in my formula, though the notation may have been confusing for you. Furthermore, it's obvious that p in the title is a scalar and p in the projection formula is a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall from calculus that the projection of a point $\vec{p}$ onto a line through the origin with direction vector $\vec{w}$ is the unique point $t\vec{w}$ on that line such that the vector from $t\vec{w}$ to $\vec{p}$ is perpendicular to the line, which gives an equation for $t$:
$$
             (\vec{p}-t\vec{w})\cdot \vec{w} = 0, \\
                t = \frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{w}}{\vec{w}\cdot\vec{w}}.
$$
And, the point of projection of $\vec{p}$ on the line is
$$
               \frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{w}}{\vec{w}\cdot\vec{w}}\vec{w}
$$
It turns out this same procedure works in an aribtrary inner product space, and the orthogonal projection is the same as the closest point projection, just as it is in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, even if the inner product space is complex.

Comment: I'm confused because the result you get from the top equation is: w-transpose p = t (w dot w) by the distributed property of dot products. However, to get my formula, the expression, (w dot w), should be square rooted.

Comment: @DaBuj : Your formula at the top, in your problem statement, is the same as mine. I put the vector $\vec{w}$ on the right because the fraction is a scalar. Dot product for a real space is transpose of column vector times a column vector, which is the same as Euclidean dot problem, and the same as an inner product. I'm using $\cdot$ as Euclidean dot product here, but that's optionally a matrix operation. Is there something I'm still missing in this explanation?

Comment: I understand. However, w dot w is not the same as the l2 norm of w.

Comment: The inner product of a vector with itself is the square of the norm of the vector: $(w,w)=\|w\|^{2}$. That allows you to write $\frac{p\cdot w}{w\cdot w}w=\left[p\cdot(\frac{1}{\|w\|}w)\right](\frac{1}{\|w\|}w)$, which may look more familiar to you, due to the fact that $\frac{1}{\|w\|}w$ is a unit vector.